# Coercion between uint types

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I have a problem in general when Matlab is unable to work out how to logically store values of differing `uint` types. For example:

```
tempC = {uint8(5) uint16(16)}
```

For me, it seems logical to be able to convert this into a matrix of type integer using `cell2mat(tempC)`, which returns

```
>> cell2mat(tempC)
Error using cell2mat (line 45)
All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.
```

Of course, I understand that the truncation behaviour of integers depends on the type (e.g. `uint8` forces all numbers greater than 255 to be 255), however, in this case I would say it would be safe enough to output `cell2mat(tempC)` with `uint16` type. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell2mat` will not work if there are cells of differing types. `cell2mat` merges the cells together into a matrix, but matrix elements in MATLAB **must all share the same type**.  This is fundamental to how MATLAB works with numeric matrices.  If you didn't have all of the same type, then you should use cell arrays... which is what they are for.

However, one thing I can suggest is figure out the type of all of the elements in your matrix, then iterate through each cell and cast them all to be the largest precision type.  You can then use `cell2mat` on this intermediate result to complete the conversion.  However, what I have written doesn't actually require calling `cell2mat` in the end.  You'll see later.

Something like this:

```
%// Get all of the possible types in the array
types = unique(cellfun(@class, tempC, 'uni', 0));

%// Figure out the largest type
vals = cellfun(@(x) double(intmax(x)), types);
[~,ind_max] = max(vals);

%// Cast all values to this type
class_max = types{ind_max};
tempC = cellfun(@(x) cast(x, class_max), tempC);
```

We first determine all of the possible classes that your cell array contains.  We then figure out which of the types is the largest of them all.  This can be done by using [`intmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intmax.html) on each of the types.  `intmax` tells you the largest possible integer that is available for that type, so we basically choose the type that generates the largest possible integer.  Take note that I had to cast to `double` as the output of `intmax` certainly does output the maximum associated for an integer type, but the output is also **cast** to that type.  This is required so that I can combine all of these elements into an array of the same type - `double`.

Once we get the type producing the maximum possible integer, we then go through the cell array and cast all of the values to this type.  Take note that I used [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) for the final call which outputs a numeric array - no need to use `cell2mat` here.  In the last line of code, I use [`cast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) to cast all of the numbers in the cell array to this type, thus achieving "coercion".

Using your example array, this is what I get, as well as what class the final array is in:

```
>> tempC

tempC =

      5     16

>> class(tempC)

ans =

uint16
```

Comment: thanks, this is very useful. I found out that it is is even worse if you use `table2array` as this function seems to coerce down to the first integer type it sees.

Comment: Glad I could help! I didn't know that about table2array... Yuck!